# Can I call a class name that has a space at the end of it?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to call the class for the following:

```
class="content_list_link "
```

I dont have the option to correct the actual source of this and need to be able to style that class.

I have tried to just call it as .content_list_link  and as a.content_list_link as it is in an a tag.

Any input on this would be appreciated.

Problem solved by: [Can I call a class name that has a space at the end of it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15744791/can-i-call-a-class-name-that-has-a-space-at-the-end-of-it#comment22372988_15744821)

Comment: No, but calling `content_list_link` should work.

Comment: *It is in an `a` tag*? What is 'it,' in context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, spaces just separate classes.

That means you can style using:

```
.content_list_link { }
```

As that's what is seen as the name of the class.

It could be such that `class='content_list_link otherClass'`, and then you'll see how you can style either, or both. If you're having trouble applying the style, then the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: hmm, still doesnt work. I think it may actually just be a problem with trying to set a background color for it. I am able to set the font weight to bold but cant cet any other properties...

Comment: also, if i go into the developer tool in chrome and add  style="background-color:red" to the a href it changes the background color

Comment: In the developer tool you should be able to see if it's being overwritten by another style definition. Or to debug if that is the problem you can use `!important` like this `background-color:red !important;`